# Send HTML output table with coloured cells in email body using smtplib

Tags: python, html, smtplib

I am trying to send an automated email with a table displayed in the email body. The table has 2 columns and the background colour of the cells in column 1 change depending on the value of the cells in column 2.

This is the html template I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Colored Cells</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Available Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
            <tr style="background-color: {{ 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5)' if item.check == True else 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5)' }}">
                <td>{{ item.column1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run my python code and create a html output using this template I get exactly what I want. However, when I try and place this table in an email body, the colours don't show up (the rest of the table appears fine).

This is python code I'm using

```
def python_mail(sender_email, rec_email, email_text):

     smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)  # Outward facing interface
     smtp_server.ehlo()
     smtp_server.starttls()  # Helps in Secure Connection
     smtp_server.ehlo
     smtp_server.login(sender_email, 'password123')
     smtp_server.sendmail(sender_email, rec_email, email_text)
     smtp_server.close()
```

And this is the rest of the python code (where html_output_colour is the output html and is working fine when I output it as a html and open it in a browser):

```
    email_str += "Start of email body"

    sender_email = "name@gmail.com"
    rec_email = "name2@gmail.com"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    html_part = MIMEText(html_output_colour, 'html')
    msg.attach(html_part)

    msg["Subject"] = subject

    # Send Email
    python_mail(sender_email, rec_email, msg.as_string())
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work please?